# process form using codeigniter's built in functions

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, built-in

I would like to make form utilizing codeigniter wherein I use the built in functions

```
$this->input->post();
```

Upon submitting the form let, I would like for the person to know the number of times this form was submitted. Please, keep in mind, I am new to codeigniter and so I would like a good explanation.

This is the form that I would like to work with.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>The FORM</title> 
<body>
    <form action="" name="myform" method="post">
      First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
      Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastname"> 
      <input tpe="submit"> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I will not be storing in database. I also want to use CI Sessions.

Comment: Do you want to store form data to database? In that case - number of records = 'number of times form was submitted'? Also, you can use native php sessions, or CI sesions... Not sure that i understand your question...

Comment: The form will not be stored in database and I want to use CI SESSIONS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `form_open()` instead of `<form>`.

You need to put the logic to update sessions in your controller.

In your controller:

```
$this->load->library('session');

$data = array(
                   'firstname'  => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                   'lastname'     => $this->input->post('lastname'),
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

All of this information is in the Codeigniter documentation.  You should really check that out first, it has a lot of good examples.

[Codeigniter info on sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

[Codeigniter info on forms](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Also you have a typo in your submit button, it says `input tpe` instead of `input type`